# Ruby SimpleCov 0.0 LOC with stand alone .rb code

Tags: ruby, code-coverage, simplecov

I am trying to use SimpleCov to gather code coverage information but I can't seem to understand how it works. It always give me 0.0% LOC. Do I need to do something to make it work?

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
SimpleCov.command_name 'Unit Tests'

def foo
  puts '12345'
end

foo
```

I see the following output:

$ ruby mytest.rb

12345

Coverage report generated for Unit Tests to /private/tmp/simpletest/coverage. 0.0 / 0.0 LOC (100.0%) covered.

Do I have to use it under rspec or some special environment? Can I not just enable code coverage for arbitrary code?

Comment: There is only one method in your question and no test at all. Why would you expect Simplecov not to report 0% test coverage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleCov filters the original source file itself out of the coverage report. To make it work standalone like this, you need to put your test code into a separate file:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
SimpleCov.command_name 'Unit Tests'

require_relative 'my_code'
foo
```

Then in `my_code.rb`:

```
def foo
  puts '12345'
end
```

Now you will get a proper report.